# pwoerdns only replicates after I manually re-creater the slave zone

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, powerdns

Hi guys I have two master/slave PowerDNS servers with MySQL backend, which is supposed to be replicated using PowerDNS replication itself (not MySQL replication). But the slave node will get the updates when I re-create the slave zone using pdnsutl.
here are my server ips:

```
master 192.168.122.10
slave  192.168.122.20
```

here is my setup on master:

```
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=192.168.122.10
gmysql-user=root
gmysql-password=sunset@123
gmysql-dbname=pdns
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=53
log-dns-details=on
allow-axfr-ips=192.168.122.20
disable-axfr=no
master=yes
```

and here is slave:

```
launch=gmysql
gmysql-host=192.168.122.20
gmysql-user=root
gmysql-password=sunset@123
gmysql-dbname=pdns
local-address=0.0.0.0
local-port=53
log-dns-details=on
slave=yes
slave-cycle-interval=60
disable-axfr=yes
allow-notify-from=192.168.122.10
superslave=yes
```

can somebody help, please?

Comment: I only got this message once when I create slave zone in slave server AXFR-in zone: 'example.com', primary: '192.168.122.10', zone committed with serial 0

Comment: but this will never occurs again

Comment: aslong the serial is not changed it will not be transferred